# Multiple different php pages need to be friendly URL - url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have php website has multiple different php pages:

```
Example:
http://www.mywebsite.com/post.php?group_id=10&post_id=1
http://www.mywebsite.com/image.php?group_id=10&img_id=1
http://www.mywebsite.com/poll.php?group_id=10&poll_id=1
http://www.mywebsite.com/group.php?group_id=10
http://www.mywebsite.com/user.php?uid=158
....
```

I need these URLs to be like the following:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post/10/1
http://www.mywebsite.com/image/10/1
http://www.mywebsite.com/poll/10/1
http://www.mywebsite.com/group/10
http://www.mywebsite.com/user/158
....
```

Note: Not these pages just I have, I have many pages like this these page.

my htaccess file as the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>     
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

the problem in my htaccess redirect to single index page, how can i make htaccess redirect to each page with its params.

Answer (score 0):

Have new rules to handle 2 parameters and one parameter separately:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>     
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(group)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?group_id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(user)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?uid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(image)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?group_id=$2&img_id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(poll|post)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?group_id=$2&$1_id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using htaccess is not a good options as you have so many pages.

In a long run it's not maintainable.
Please use any routing module (like http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine)

Answer (score 0):

another one solution by adding some unique paths to the rules,

```
example:

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)\.html$ /posts.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^polls/([^/]*)\.html$ /polls.php?id=$1 [L]

result:

domain.com?posts.php?id=421 -> domain.com/news/421.html
domain.com?polls.php?id=17 -> domain.com/polls/17.html
```