# Shortening URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**My folder structure is:**

modules

- admin

  - index.php
- login

  - login.php
  - signup.php
- articles

  - articles.php

**My current URL is:**

localhost/modules/admin/index.php

localhost/modules/login/login.php

localhost/modules/articles/articles.php

**I want to change it to:**

localhost/index

localhost/login

localhost/articles

Since i a beginner in using .htaccess file, pls help me how i can change the URL using .htaccess file

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170495/multiple-different-php-pages-need-to-be-friendly-url-url-rewrite

Comment: I think you have not understood the question correctly, its not only about removing the .php extension but removing the folder structure as well from the URL

Comment: I posted the answer, hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure makes it difficult to have a universal rule but you should be able to use these rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(index)/?$ /modules/admin/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(login|articles)/?$ /modules/$1/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index([^/]*) /admin/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login([^/]*) /login/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup([^/]*) /login/signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^articles([^/]*) /articles/articles.php [L]
```